# ListView control does not draw new items after first time

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, .net-4.0

I have the following code which puts a bunch of items into a listview. However after filling it once, it won't show the next update, *or the column headers*, although the scrollbar does get smaller as I step through each iteration, and I can scroll fine, but there's nothing there. Before I fill it the first time it shows the column headers. **View** is set to **Detail**.

```
    private static ListViewItem NewListViewItem (ItemData item)
    {
        return new ListViewItem(new string[] { 
                item.ListID, 
                item.ItemName, 
                item.Description, 
                item.ManuPartNumber, 
                item.UPC 
            });

    }
    private static void updateList(List<ItemData> items)
    {
        list1.Items.Clear();

        foreach (ItemData item in items)
            list1.Items.Add(NewListViewItem(item));
        list1.RedrawItems(0, list1.Items.Count - 1, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, problem solved. Somewhere else, I had written `list1.Clear()` which cleared everything, including the columns for displaying the details. So I changed that to `list1.Items.Clear()` and that took care of it.

Comment: Duh! Had the same problem. Thanks for posting the answer!